# AccessViolationException If I declare the variable as Public Members, instead of local variable

Tags: c#

I have 2 interop data structure as private member in a class,

```
public class RunInterop
{

        private AlphaShapeCg _alphaHandler;
        private DoubleCgList alphaLevels;
        private FaceCgList faceCgList;
    public RunInterop()
        {
            faceCgList =new FaceCgList();
            alphaLevels = new DoubleCgList();
            Interop_Init(ref _alphaHandler, ref faceCgList, ref alphaLevels);

           Interop_Run(ref _alphaHandler);
        }
}
```

The problem now, is that I will get an `System.AccessViolationException` at `Interop_Run` line.

However, if I rewrite my code in the following manner:

```
public class RunInterop
{
   private AlphaShapeCg _alphaHandler;
    public RunInterop()
        {
           var faceCgList =new FaceCgList();
           var alphaLevels = new DoubleCgList();
            Interop_Init(ref _alphaHandler, ref faceCgList, ref alphaLevels);

           Interop_Run(ref _alphaHandler);
        }
}
```

Then I wouldn't have any problem. Any idea why this is the case?

**Edit: What is really puzzling is that, why, if I declare both the `faceCgList` and `alphaLevels` as local variables, the problem would just go away?**

Comment: where is `_alphaHandler` declared?

Comment: @DanielA.White, question updated

Comment: where is _alphaHandler initialized?

Comment: @Graviton - Is that formatting intentional?

Comment: @Graviton - Do you have mixed mode debugging enabled with the debug symbols for whatever you are using (DirectX?)? I wonder if the interop side of this code would give in terms of a callstack?

Comment: @RitchMelton, yes, I do have mixed debugging enabled. The problem is that the `_alphaHandler` is a very complex object, and the error just doesn't make sense ( one of its variable is a null, even though it shouldn't be)

Comment: @Graviton - Its obviously a bad ptr dereference, but why?

Comment: That's the problem; the thing that compounds the mystery is that why, if I declare both the `faceCgList` and `alphaLevels` as local variables, the problem would just go away?

Comment: @Graviton - I could see that. Something about how references to locals are marshalled vs class members?

Comment: Are their any difference in how the referecnes are marshalled in class or as local members?

Answer (score 0):

What happens in **Interop_Init** and **Interop_Run**?  You are passing the two members **alphaLevels** and **faceCgList** into **Interop_Init** - maybe it is keeping some reference to them that are used again when calling **Interop_Run**, at which point it might appear to be accessing the private member of a different class?

**Edit:** just an idea :)

```
public class RunInterop
{
    private AlphaShapeCg _alphaHandler;
    private DoubleCgList _alphaLevels;
    private FaceCgList _faceCgList;

    public RunInterop()
    {
        AlphaShapeCg faceCgList = new FaceCgList();
        DoubleCgList alphaLevels = new DoubleCgList();
        Interop_Init(ref _alphaHandler, ref faceCgList, ref alphaLevels);
        Interop_Run(ref _alphaHandler);
        _alphaLevels = alphaLevels;
        _faceCgList = faceCgList;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I found this [link](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) explaining how the managed / unmanaged marshaling works in Mono - I'm struggling to find a similar informative article for Microsoft's dotNET Framework, but my guess would be that it should work in a similar way.  Here's one quote from the article:

> Additionally, if (a) the structure is located on the stack, and (b)
>   the structure contains only blittable types, then if you pass a
>   structure to an unmanaged function by-reference, the structure will be
>   passed directly to the unmanaged function, without an intermediate
>   unmanaged memory copy.

Comment: I don't think so, the reason is because  if I declare both the faceCgList and alphaLevels as local variables, the problem would just go away?

Comment: When you declare them as private members, dotNET tries to protect that memory space when you move into unmanaged code.  With local variables that is probably not the case.

Comment: It depends when you want to have access to these structs as members in stead of local variables.  I added an idea where you assign private members to local variables after Interup_Run, but if you need to set them up elsewhere before calling RunInterop you could set the local variables to copies of their member counterparts before calling Interop_Init in stead.

Comment: Thanks Veldmuis, as for **maybe it is keeping some reference to them that are used again when calling Interop_Run, at which point it might appear to be accessing the private member of a different class?**, may I know how can this happen? Seems impossible.

Comment: My initial wording might not have been correct.  In c# each struct [S] (either alphaLevels / faceCgList) exists in its allocated memory space [M] and since the member is declared as private, dotNET only allows the class RunInterop access to [M].  [S] is passed by reference to Interop_Init, which means the unmanaged code will also reference [M].  This memory reference could again be accessed when Interop_Run is called, but since it is not passed in via one of the parameters dotNET picks this up as an invalid reference to [M].

Comment: **Run is called, but since it is not passed in via one of the parameters dotNET picks this up as an invalid reference to [M]**, how can it be invalid? Both the alphaLevels and faceCgList are private members in a class, and so they shouldn't change their value when in different methods

Comment: I didn't mean they are references to invalid memory, but that they may not be accessed from outside of the RunInterop class (I am assuming that Interop_Run is an external method that is therefore not part of RunInterop).